Resonance in allenes
I was told that Propa-1,2-diene does not show resonance but Buta-1,2,3-triene does (such that electrons of first pi bond are delocalised, those of second are localised, those of third are again delocalised). But I know that for resonance, system must be planar and in conjugation (alternate single and double bonds). Since there is lack of conjugation in both compounds, why is it so that one can show resonance and the other cannot?

Conjugation does not mean alternate single and double bonds.

The resonance in Buta-1,2,3-triene arises because the first and third pi bonds are in parallel planes, which allows partial overlap of their pi orbitals. This creates an indirect resonance-like effect, where the electrons in the first and third bonds show limited delocalization despite the absence of traditional alternation of single and double bonds. This is not classical resonance but a case of orbital interaction that mimics partial delocalization.
And as the two $\pi-$bonds in Propa-1,2-diene are orthogonal to each other, hence resonance effect is not seen here.
So, Buta-1,2,3-triene shows partial delocalization while Propa-1,2-diene does not.

The situation for buta-1,2,3-triene delocalization is not so different from the butadiene case, where the lowest energy MO is delocalized over the 4 carbons, so I think it is fair to say just delocalized rather than partially delocalized.
